# Unusual result from prediction using categorical_crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Preface: I'm completely new to Machine Learning, so it's probably an easy solution.

Expected: First I trained a CNN model using binary_crossentropy on two classes (good and bad) with a validation accuracy of 97%, submitted new images to prediction and got expected results (the two new images were sorted correctly with a probability of being correct in the 90's.

```
1 #print(model.predict_classes(img))
0.965675 #print(model.predict_proba(img))
```

Issue: Now I'm attempting to switch to categorical_crossentropy to use three classes (b1 b2 b3), the model trains with 96% accuracy. I submit 3 new images to prediction, 2 images should match and one is out of left field and shouldn't match anything. All three images supposedly match with 1. probability.

```
[1] #print(model.predict_classes(img))
[[0. 1. 0.]] #print(model.predict_proba(img))

[2]
[[0. 0. 1.]]

[1]
[[0. 1. 0.]]
```

Question: Why would an image out of left field match one of the classes with a model trained to 96%? Why are all the probabilities in the categorical "1." (100%)?

Appendix:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: What do you mean by **image out of left field** ?

Comment: @BenjaminBreton Image that looks nothing like the classes or trained images.

Comment: Okay, the thing is that you trained your classifier to split between class one or class two, if you didn't provide enough examples for class three, your classifier is always going to try to put the image in class 1 or class 2. You would need a lot of **negative examples** in class 3 for your algorithm to work as expected.

Comment: @BenjaminBreton I guess I see that. I mean I have 1000 images for class 1 and class 2 but only 400 for class 3. But that still doesn't explain why everything is probability "1." (100%). It shouldn't always be 100%

Comment: Is your dataset clean ? are the labels right ? You can use [data-augmentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) to improve your model and make it more resilient.

Comment: @BenjaminBreton it worked fine for binary_crossentropy as I stated above. I got a decent probability. All images are 1 channel grayscale of all the same size.

Comment: Well,the predict function always replaces the highest value (most probable class) of the softmax with 1 and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Your intention may be to take a look at the Softmax than the prediction values.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa Yes, but I'm using predict_proba, which should give me the probability as it did in the first example. I understand it's 1 or 0 for class identification.

Comment: Can you just try with model.predict

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa model.predict gives me the same result as predict_proba, apparently it's smashing the probability. ugh

Comment: Well based on the issue: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2524
model.predict_proba does not compute the probability, instead recommends to use softmax. I do see it is an old issue. However, the issue still remains an open one.

Comment: Are you normalizing/rescaling the images before calling model.predict?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro stated in previous comment "All images are 1 channel grayscale of all the same size"

Comment: @dyslexicjedi That is not normalization, I mean the division by 255 to get pixels in the [0, 1] range.